# How do you make SubmitChanges only submit a particular change and not all previous changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, submitchanges

The ASP.NET linq SubmitChanges method commits changes for all previous database modifications since the last time it was called.

I have a case where I do something like the following:

```
ClassX x = new Abc.Linq.ClassX();
DataContext.InsertOnSubmit(x);

ClassY y = new Abc.Linq.ClassXY();
DataContext.InsertOnSubmit(y);

DataContext.SubmitChanges();//x and y are committed to the database
```

I would like to insert y but not X in the line above.
Then I would like to insert X with another call to SubmitChanges() sometime later.
I have to execute the code in the order shown.

Is that possible?
Or should I be calling something other than SubmitChanges()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use separate DataContexts for this. The DataContext is simply a wrapper for data access, and a set of pending changes. It does not support partial commits of its changelist. InsertOnSubmit does what it says it does - is there a reason you need to call that before you actually want it submitted? Perhaps if you elaborated on the problem that's locking you into this execution order we could provide a better solution.

Comment: +1 for separate DataContexts, given this particular scenario.